# "I heated it thoroughly before I ate it" or "I heated it thoroughly before I eating it"?

Tags: sentence-structure

What is the best structure to express the sentence?

Past simple+ "before"+ Past simple

or

Past simple+ "before"+ verb+"ing"

Comment: "before **I** ate it" -- you should not omit the pronoun **I**

Comment: It doesn't really matter which you choose, as long as you make the change mentioned by @CopperKettle. The participle form is just fine, as long as there is no change of subject. Otherwise, you would need to construct your verb: "I heated it thoroughly before **you** ate it".

Comment: I've already modified the title of the question "before I ate it"

Comment: Your pre-edit sentence "I heated it thoroughly before eating it" sounds good to my American ear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The best (or, if you want to be picky *better* structure, since there are only two structures in question, although *best* is sometimes used: *May the best man win* before a boxing match where there are only two contestants...)

Anyway the better structure is

> I heated it thoroughly before I ate it.

Why? Because using finite verbs (heated, ate) is more natural and colloquial in everyday English, especially in such a day to day situation such as this one.

Many writers also suggest avoiding the progressive whenever possible.

See [Prefer Simple Tenses over Progressive Tenses](http://grammartips.homestead.com/progressive.html).

Comment: There's no progressive in *I heated it thoroughly before eating it*.

Comment: @Araucaria Which is why I suggest it is the better structure. So apparently you misread what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. What did you mean by "Many writers also suggest avoiding the progressive whenever possible?"